# Why does omitting the push_back make the loop run slower?

Tags: c++, performance, gcc, g++

Consider this program, which I am compiling on Cygwin with gcc 5.4.0 and command line `g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -pedantic -O2 timing.cpp -o timing`.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string generateitem()
{
    return "a";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> items;

    std::chrono::steady_clock clk;
    auto start(clk.now());

    std::string item;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3000000; ++i)
    {
        item = generateitem();
        items.push_back(item); // *********
    }

    auto stop(clk.now());
    std::cout
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
            (stop-start).count()
        << " ms\n";
}
```

I consistently get a reported time of around 500 ms. However, if I comment out the starred line, thus omitting the `push_back` to the `vector`, the time reported is around 700 ms.

Why does not pushing to the `vector` make the loop run slower?

Comment: Do you mean "Why does pushing to the `vector` make the loop run faster?" The "not" in your original question (and the title) implies that calling `push_back` makes it slower, but your numbers say it makes it faster.

Comment: Umm @KenY-N it does sound like he mean what you say, but I take his question word by word he doesn't say that! Eric, with `g++ 4.2.1` I was not able to reproduce this. I got 158ms and without the `push_back` 38ms, not 700ms.... To the person that casted a close vote: If you are about to cast a close vote, choose the correct option please.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I fixed the question title and body. To confirm, the extra line makes the program faster.

Comment: @gsamaras The correct option in whose opinion?

Comment: Having another go now the title has been cleared up: without looking at the assembler output, perhaps what is happening is that each new `item` is being moved into the vector, but then when it is commented out, each new `item` needs to be deleted. Perhaps if you change the scope of `items` so that it gets deleted before measuring the time?

Comment: I have g++ 6.1.1 and I'm with @gsamaras here. With `push_back` I get 495ms. Without `push_back` I get 93ms. `push_back` should have more overhead and make your code slower...

Comment: I find it can be hard to nail down what the compiler produces in simple timing tests like this. I would make sure you use your vector so that the optimizer doesn't just ignore it altogether. After the timer stops you could print out the size of the vector for instance. `std::cout << items.size();` is an opaque function so calling that will prevent the compiler from removing the vector.

Comment: Having said that in my test it is 3 times faster when I comment out the `push_back()`.

Comment: Can't seem to duplicate your results either. Tried with VC++ and g++, both with and without optimization, and in every case it seems to run faster with the `push_back` commented out, exactly as expected.

Comment: You may also want to time it with items.reserve(3000000);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run the test now, and the problem is that in the `push_back` version, the `item` string is not being deallocated. Changing the code to:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string generateitem()
{
    return "a";
}

int main()
{

    std::chrono::steady_clock clk;
    auto start(clk.now());
{
    std::vector<std::string> items;
    std::string item;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3000000; ++i)
    {
        item = generateitem();
        items.push_back(item); // *********
    }
}
    auto stop(clk.now());
    std::cout
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
            (stop-start).count()
        << " ms\n";
}
```

Gives the expected behaviour of, on my CygWin machine, about the same time for both options, as we measure all the deallocations this time.

To explain further, the original code is basically:

```
allocate items
start clock
repeat 3000000 times
    allocate std::string("a")
    move std::string("a") to end of items array
stop clock
deallocate 3000000 strings
```

So, the performance is dominated by 3000000 allocations. Now, if we comment out the `push_back()`, we get:

```
allocate items
start clock
repeat 3000000 times
    allocate std::string("a")
    deallocate std::string("a")
stop clock
```

Now we measure 3000000 allocations and 3000000 deallocations, so it should be obvious that it will actually be slower. My suggestion for moving the `items` vector deallocation into the timing span means that we have either with `push_back()`:

```
start clock
allocate items
repeat 3000000 times
    allocate std::string("a")
    move std::string("a") to end of items array
deallocate 3000000 strings
stop clock
```

Or without `push_back()`:

```
start clock
allocate items
repeat 3000000 times
    allocate std::string("a")
    deallocate std::string("a")
deallocate empty array
stop clock
```

So, both ways round we measure 3000000 allocations and deallocations, so the code will take basically the same time.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that put me on the right track. I have now confirmed that despite the claims of the GCC docs, the new string implementation is not enabled by default, at least in Cygwin. So the copy-on-write semantics were preventing the deallocations. Adding -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 to the command line produces the expected behavior.

Comment: What does "the `item` string is not being deallocated" mean?

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question of why including the `push_back` appeared to speed up the time taken to get to just before deallocation.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I've added more explanation.

Comment: I see, so your theory is the compiler is optimising the `push_back` and moving the string rather than copying it? In that case, a non-optimised/debug build should show the `push_back` version as slower rather than faster.

Comment: @JonathanPotter It only works out this way due to the copy-on-write semantics. The string is "copied" into the vector but that's basically just incrementing a refcount.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ken Y-N's answer I can now give the complete answer to my own question.

The code was compiled againat a version of the standard library that implements copy-on-write for `std::string`. That is, when the string is copied, the buffer for the string contents is not duplicated, and both string objects use the same buffer. Duplication only happens when one of the strings is written to. Thus the life cycle of an allocated string buffer is as follows:

1. It is created in the `generateitem` function.
2. It comes out of the `generateitem` function via RVO.
3. It is assigned to `item`. (This is a move operation because the `std::string` is a temporary.)
4. The call to `push_back` duplicates the `std::string`, but not the buffer. Now there are two `std::string`s sharing a buffer.
5. On the next iteration of the loop, the next string is moved into `item`. Now, the only `std::string` object using the buffer is the one in the vector.
6. When the vector is destroyed on completion of `main`, the reference counts for all the buffers drop to 0, so they are deallocated.

Thus, none of the buffers is deallocated during the time measured.

If we eliminate the call to `push_back`, then step 4 doesn't happen. In step 5, the reference count for the buffer then drops to 0, so it is deallocated then, during the time being measured. This explains why the measured time increases.

Now, according to the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html#libstdcxx), GCC 5 was supposed to have replaced the copy-on-write string class with a newer one that doesn't use copy-on-write. But, apparently, the old version is still used by default in Cygwin. If we add `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1` to the command line, we get the new string class, and with this we get the results we would expect.